# jQuery Masonry wrong top position

Tags: resize, position, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap with fixed layout along with jQuery Masonry on a specific page.

It's working, however starting from the second row the top positions of the divs are miscalculated and are partly covering the elements of the first row.

It looks like the script quits before rearranging the elements.

Strangely, when I open the inspector in Chrome or slightly resize the viewport the divs are jumping to their correct positions. Refreshing the page sometimes helps, sometimes doesn't...

My masonry script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.span9').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.span3',
        columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
        return containerWidth / 3;
        }
    });
});
```

Is this normal behaviour? Should I add `window.resize` to the above script?

Placing the masonry script in the page itself or in the header, footer doesn't change it's behaviour.

I'm calling masonry.js right after jQuery, before any other Bootstrap js.

Comment: No, adding `resize` breaks masonry...

Comment: second row? are you placing your divs inside rows? what elements are you shuffling with masonry?

Comment: Oh no, sorry for the confusion, not "boostrap row". I used the word row theoretically here. All the elements are spans and are inside one span, as you can see in the script above.

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a sample page with your issue?

Comment: I can get you access to the site, how about that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just read the help Section here http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/help.html

The Script runs before all images have been loaded, you have to trigger it after the window loaded

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options...
  });
});
```

Comment: I'll give it go. It makes sense, since the images in the blocks don't have dimensions defined as the layout is fluid.

Comment: Thanks @Blac for pointing out the help section, it seems that with the imagesLoaded plugin the blocks don't overlap each other.

Comment: alternatively you can specify height for `img` tag if it's same

Comment: This is the right answer, but now (in 2020 :) `load` in jquery is written `.on("load", function(){ ...`: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/